# Use Hidden form field to store JSON and then parse it. JSON parse fails

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core

*Please excuse if this is duplicate.*

I have a hidden form field and I store a base64 encoded string
in which represents a serialised object in JSON format.

When I try to deserialise the object, I get a parse error.
The form value after it has been base64 decoded results in a "string",

and trying to use `JSON.parse(decoded_field_value`) causes a parsing error, and a *OBJECT* cannot be created.

*Here are some snippets of the relevant code:*

**Controller C#**

```
    private string ToBase64(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }

    // the model holds the hidden form field value
    model.Qt = ToBase64(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(qTypes));
```

**Cshtml:**

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Qt)
```

**RawHtml:**

```
     <input id="b64Field" name="Qt" type="hidden"             
            value="WwB7ACIASQBkACIAOgAxACwAIgBO......=="/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    var field  = $('input:hidden[name="Qt"]').val();
    var ds = atob(field);
    var p = JSON.parse(ds);
```

**Values:**

```
    field = "WwB7ACIASQBkACIAOgAxACwAIgBOAG...."
    ds = "[{"Id":1,"X":"ValX"},{"Id":2,"Y":"ValY"}]"
```

**Error Message:**

```
 VM1346:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 1
 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

I can see the problem is that the ds is not valid JSON,
as it should be 
`ds = [{"Id":1,"X":"ValX"},{"Id":2,"Y":"ValY"}]`

How do I fix this error using Javascript or C# in the backend.

Comment: How did you check the value un your `ds` variable? Seems like your quotation marks may be causing the problem

Comment: I hope I understand you correct, I used Chrome's debugger to see the values.
And yes the quotes are the problem.

Comment: The type of ds is a string: typeof(ds); "string"

Comment: Seems to work OK - https://jsfiddle.net/y8eoLbkz/ .

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for that, but I have noticed your ds is different to mine,
yours = "[{\"Id\":1,\"X\":\"ValX\"},{\"Id\":2,\"\Y\":\"ValY\"}]";
mine = "[{"Id":1,"X":"ValX"},{"Id":2,"Y":"ValY"}]";

Comment: If you check the `console.log` entries, you'll see they are the same @Wayne.

Comment: @mjwills yes you are right they are the same; yet my JSON.parse gives an error and you're code not.

Comment: Which means the string likely isn't the same. Please share the exact value of `field`.